# Which command to use to find all files/folders with non-default permissions?

Tags: permissions, files, find

Suppose I have a folder, containing other files and folders, and I'd like to find out recursively which subfiles and subfolders have non-default permissions (i.e., not 644 or 755).

Which command can be used to do that? The command should output a list of the relevant files and folders, and their permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the entire task using just `find`:

```
$ find . -type f ! \( -perm 755 -o -perm 644 \) -printf "%m\t%p\n"
```

#### Example

Make all permutations of permissions (000-777).

```
$ touch {0..7}{0..7}{0..7}
$ for i in {0..7}{0..7}{0..7}; do chmod $i $i;done
$ find . -type f | wc -l
512
```

A sample of our `find` command's list of files it's finding:

```
$ find . -type f ! \( -perm 755 -o -perm 644 \) -printf "%m\t%p\n"| head -10
734 ./734
376 ./376
555 ./555
663 ./663
256 ./256
336 ./336
2   ./002
152 ./152
527 ./527
416 ./416
```

If we run our `find` command we can confirm that it worked:

```
$ find . -type f ! \( -perm 755 -o -perm 644 \) -printf "%m\t%p\n" | grep 755
$ find . -type f ! \( -perm 755 -o -perm 644 \) -printf "%m\t%p\n" | grep 644
```

Comment: permissions are on 12 bits, not 9.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I know I was just showing the common ones.

Comment: For robustness, I'd write 0755 etc (it is octal, some idiotic tool might understand decimal...)

Comment: @vonbrand, if a `find` implementation treated `-perm 755` as `-perm 01363`, or a `chmod` implementation treated `chmod 755` as `chmod 01362`, you'd think someone would have noticed by now and reported it as a bug. Note that there is only one implementation of `find` that supports `-printf`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, perhaps not `find(1)`, but elsewhere... I got into the habit of making octal for file permissions explicit when I got bitten by decimal (decades ago, don't remember much details).

Answer (score 3):

```
find . \( \
  -type d ! -perm 755 -o \
  -type l ! -perm 777 -o \
  -type f ! \( -perm 644 -o -perm 755 \) -o \
  ! -type f ! -type l ! -type d ! -perm 644 \) -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -printf "%m\t%p\n" | grep -Ev "^(755|644)"
```

Example output:

```
$ find . -printf "%m\t%p\n" | grep -Ev "^(755|644)"
777 ./a/writable/folder
777 ./another/folder
666 ./an/executable-file
```

Please note that the `egrep` command does not consider whether a line is a file or folder. As a result, files with permission 755 and folders with permission 644 would not be found by this command.

Furthermore this command is not very efficient, as `find` starts by printing all subfolders and subfiles, and only after that the files and folders are filtered by `egrep`. However, I haven't found a better method yet.

Comment: That would miss files like `-r-sr-s--T` (7550). `egrep` and `find` concurrently, there's no efficiency issue here.